# MongoDB: stored base64 buffer data and retrieved base64 does not match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am posting small sized base64 encoded images (around 100-200K each) directly into mongodb using Mongoose. Before storing I could see the content is same as what sent from the client. But the query base64 string is not same as what went in? Any idea what I am missing ?

```
    // process the add image request
app.post('/addimage', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Addimage post....");
    var qry = {'_email' : req.user.local.email, 'date' : req.body.date, 'subject' : req.body.subject };
    Item.findOne(qry, function(err, item) {
         if (err) {
             console.log('Find images failed: ' + err);
             var resp = '{"result" : "failed", "msg" : ' + err + ', "_req" : "addimage"}';
             res.send(resp);
         } else {
             if (item == null) { // item doesn't exist, create now
                 var item = new Item();
                 item._email = req.body._email;
                 item.date = req.body.date;
                 item.subject = req.body.subject;
             }

             // add image
             var image = new Image();
             image.timestamp = req.body.timestamp;
             image.contentType = req.body.contentType;
             var imgBuf = new Buffer(req.body.image, 'base64');
             image.image = imgBuf;
             item.images.push(image);

             item.save(function(err, result) {
                 if (err) {
                     console.log('Find images failed: ' + err);
                     var resp = '{"result" : "failed", "msg" : ' + err + ', "_req" : "addimage"}';
                     res.send(resp);
                 } else {
                     res.send('{"result" : "ok", _req: "addimage"}');
                     console.log("Image saved and responded to ...");
                 }
             });
         }
    });
});
```

The data string stored in req.body.image started with something like "/9j/4AAQSkZJ ..." but from mongo shell I see it different. Is it the subtype 0 for the Bindata that's causing this ?

```
> db.items.find({subject:"Science"},{'images.image':1})
```

{ "_id" : ObjectId("547382943fc884447a767d58"), "images" : [ { "image" : BinData(0,"LwA5AGoALwA0AEEAQQBRAFMAawBaAEoAUgBnAEEAQgBBAFEAQQBBAEEAUQBBAEIAQQBBAEQALwA0AFEAQgBZAFIAWABoAHAAWgBnAEEAQQBUAFUAMABBAEsAZwBBAEEAQQBBAGcAQQBBAGcARQBTAEEAQQBN

Schema:

```
var imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    timestamp   : String,
    contentType : String,
    image       : Buffer,
}, { strict: true });
imageSchema.index({ timestamp: 1}, { unique: true });

var itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_email     : {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
date       : {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
subject    : {   
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },   
images     : [imageSchema],
}, { strict: false });
itemSchema.index({ _email: 1, date: 1, subject: 1}, { unique: true });
```

Mongodb version 2.6.5, Mongoose 3.8.1, Node v0.11.6-pre

Also, tried 'utf8' / 'ascii' / 'ucs2' instead of 'base64' while creating Buffer object.

Thanks!

Comment: Noone saves images in database!!!
You must save url of images

Comment: @kaxi1993, clearly you know nothing but MongDB and more specifically GridFS. Have your self a quick search and info session to find out that yes technology has moved on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was node version ;( Restoring to 0.10.33 solved the issue !